# Display data from database and link it to new page

Tags: php, mysql

I'm able to display what I have in my table with the code below, but as you can see in the code I'm linking the rows to a new page, and on that page I'm trying to display the rest of the rows, which I have in the same table.

I mean, I have cols `ID, photo, Firstname, Lastname, Age, StreetAdd, PhoneNum, EmailAdd` in the table. I'm displaying only rows `photo, Firstname, Lastname` on the first page.

So what I'm trying to do is when the user clicks on the First name , which I displayed from the database, he will be redirected to the new page and see the rest of the info. How do I do it?

This is the PHP page which displays the three cols. I can display the rest of the cols on a new page but it's displaying all the info in the row. I want to display the individual info for each user, not the whole list. A possible example would be eBay. When you search for items, you won't see the full description until you click on the picture or the title.

```
<?php
  $con = mysql_connect("localhost","root","");
  if (!$con) {
    die('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error());
  }
  mysql_select_db("simple_login", $con);
  $result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM test ");
  echo "<table align='center' bgcolor='#F9F0F0' border='0' cellspacing='0'>
    <tr>
      <th><font color='red'>Firstname</font></th>
    </tr>";
  while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {
    echo "<tr>";
    echo "<td><a href='send.php'><img src='".$row['photo']."' \" width=\"150px\" height=\"150px\" /></a><br><br><br>";
    echo "<a href='send.php'><td align='center' style='vertical-align:text-top' width='200px'>" . $row['Firstname'] . "</td>";
    echo "<td align='center' style='vertical-align:text-top' width='200px'>" . $row['Lastname'] . "</td>";
    echo "</tr>";
  }
  echo "</table>";
  mysql_close($con);
?>
```

Comment: [**Please, don't use `mysql_*` functions in new code**](http://bit.ly/phpmsql). They are no longer maintained [and are officially deprecated](https://wiki.php.net/rfc/mysql_deprecation). See the [**red box**](http://j.mp/Te9zIL)? Learn about [*prepared statements*](http://j.mp/T9hLWi) instead, and use [PDO](http://php.net/pdo) or [MySQLi](http://php.net/mysqli) - [this article](http://j.mp/QEx8IB) will help you decide which. If you choose PDO, 
[here is a good tutorial](http://stackoverflow.com/a/14110189/1723893).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

to display individual info for each user you can use where close in query like

```
SELECT * FROM test WHERE user = bla
```

---

### **Warning**

your code is vulnerable to [sql injection](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection) you need to escape all `get` and `post` and the better approach will be using [Prepared statement](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prepared_statement)

**Good Read**

1. [How to prevent SQL injection in PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/how-to-prevent-sql-injection-in-php)
2. [**Are PDO prepared statements sufficient to prevent SQL injection?**](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12202218/1723893)

---

### **Note**

1. The entire **`ext/mysql`** PHP extension, which provides all functions named with the prefix mysql_, is [officially deprecated as of PHP v5.5.0](http://php.net/manual/en/changelog.mysql.php) and will be removed in the future. So use either `PDO` or `MySQLi`

**Good read**

1. [The mysql extension is deprecated and will be removed in the future: use mysqli or PDO instead](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13944956/the-mysql-extension-is-deprecated-and-will-be-removed-in-the-future-use-mysqli/13944958#comment19236631_13944958.)
2. [Pdo Tutorial For Beginners](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12859942/why-shouldnt-i-use-mysql-functions-in-php/14110189#14110189)

Comment: I will fix the problem with using Mysql..also WHERE user= blah works but how I'm gonna know the user name if new user registers..isn't there a way to do it automatically?

Comment: you can either do this by redirecting  user to that page after registered  or you can use ajax for that

Answer (score 3):

On you have put a text level element `a` inside a block level element `td` the cell where first name is shown. Also you didn't close `a` tag there. correct form is this.

```
echo "<td align='center' style='vertical-align:text-top' width='200px'>";
echo "<a href='send.php'>" . $row['Firstname'] . "</a></td>";
```

To get the same user bio on the `send.php` you need to pass the primary key for this row. For examle if the primary key is `id` you pass it `send.php` in query string.

```
echo "<a href='send.php?id=".$row['id']."'>" . $row['Firstname'] . "</a></td>";
```

Now in the `send.php` use `$_GET['id']` to get the primary key and use it to retrieve the user bio from db.

But **make sure you escape parameters you pass to sql database**. Dont use those variables directly! See Nullpointer's [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14179824/376535)

---

### Update 1:

When you get the primary key of a row just invoke a `SELECT *` with **`LIMIT 1`**

```
$pkey = mysql_real_escape_string($_GET['id']);
$sql = "SELECT * FROM test where id='$pkey' LIMIT 1";
/* Run this sql */
```

Comment: thanks for the correction..could you show me how do i use $_GET['id'] to get single user info..I'd be glad...that's where I'm Stuck...

Comment: tried what you pointed but I'm getting error...please show me the full code...txs

Comment: @Magna there is no full code. It depends completely on your code. What error you are getting?

Comment: Notice: Undefined index: id in C:\xampp\htdocs\send.php on line 10

Notice: Undefined variable: result in C:\xampp\htdocs\send.php on line 18
Warning: mysql_fetch_array() expects parameter 1 to be resource, null given in C:\xampp\htdocs\send.php on line 18

Comment: `mysql_fetch_array() expects parameter 1 to be resource, null given` means your previous `mysql_query` didn't succeeded.

Answer (score 0):

This should be your first page

```
<?php
  $con = mysql_connect("localhost","root","");
  if (!$con) {
    die('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error());
  }
  mysql_select_db("simple_login", $con);
  $result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM test ");
  echo "<table align='center' bgcolor='#F9F0F0' border='0' cellspacing='0'>
    <tr>
      <th><font color='red'>Firstname</font></th>
    </tr>";
  while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {
    echo "<tr>";
    echo "<td><a href='send.php'><img src='".$row['photo']."' \" width=\"150px\" height=\"150px\" /></a><br><br><br>";
    echo "<a href='send.php?".$row['id']."'><td align='center' style='vertical-align:text-top' width='200px'>" . $row['Firstname'] . "</td>";
    echo "<td align='center' style='vertical-align:text-top' width='200px'>" . $row['Lastname'] . "</td>";
    echo "</tr>";
  }
  echo "</table>";
  mysql_close($con);
?>
```

Now send.php should be

```
<?php
$con = mysql_connect("localhost","root","");
      if (!$con) {
        die('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error());
      }
      mysql_select_db("simple_login", $con);
      $sql = "SELECT * FROM test where id = " . $_Get['id'] ;
      $result = mysql_query($sql);

//then display the result here

?>
```

hope this helps

Comment: the first one is fine but send.php says Undefined variable: _Get